# Merge [azureml] and [azure-machine-learning-service]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag [azureml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azureml) has had as its tag wiki excerpt [since January 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28102321):

> please use the [azure-machine-learning-service] tag instead!

Hence, a moderator should merge the two tags, and not leave behind an abandoned pointer.